# How can I use jQuery to make a div's margin left = half it's width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to find the width of a div tag

then set it's margin-left to half of that width

using jquery.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$('#divID').css('marginLeft', function() { 
    return $(this).width()/2;
});
```

Comment: well if you know the div id, might as well just do `$("#divid").css("margin-left", $("#divid").width()/2)`

Comment: @Rodolfo Why would I make 2 jQuery calls when I can achieve in 1

Comment: @Rodolfo nah, doing it vegas way wont have to refind the element.

Comment: @Vega isn't $(this) a jquery call? I keep reading that people do stuff like `$this = $(this)` for that reason

Comment: Speaking strictly it is, but you can access it immediately without jQuery needing to traverse the whole DOM in order to find it.

Comment: @Rodolfo Correcting my prev comment.. yes it does make jQuery function call.. but it is better than `$('#div')`. Check >> http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=init << -> `$(this)` will fall in 2nd if `if (selector.nodeType)` where else `$('#divID')` will go inside `if (typeof selector === "string")` and inside it will determine that it is an ID.

Comment: oh ok that makes sense. Guess the very best then would be something like `$d=$("#divID"); $d.css("margin-left", $d.width()/2)`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div').css({'marginLeft' : $('div').width()/2});
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/HM4K4/)**

**Pure JS**

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
div.style.marginLeft = div.offsetWidth/2 +'px';
```

**[Pure JS Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/L5JZa/)**

Comment: I think `$(this)` in your code is `window` object not the div object.

Comment: you can use margin-left too I believe, less confusing

Comment: @Vega bah yeah good call. I figured that out once I did it w/o jQuery

Comment: @MoinZaman yeah that was my falt, I had to edit it. Vegas solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.foo').css('margin-left', $('div.foo').width()/2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elem = $('#divID');
elem.css('margin-left',elem.width() / 2);
```